# Application wide rails variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following code to change the background picture of a page if the user added a link to the picture from their profile page. However I'd like this to apply to all pages instead of just the one the code is currently in.

I know I can put the code in each page individually but that is obviously not ideal. I tried putting it in the application.js and application.html.erb files but it didn't work.

I believe it has something to do with gon making those variables only available to the page they are located in?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  if(gon.backgroundPicture) {
      var background = gon.backgroundPicture;
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + background + ")";
    };     
});

<% if current_user.try(:student?) || current_user.try(:supervisor?) %> 
  <% if current_user.background_picture != :null %>
    <% @gon.backgroundPicture = current_user.background_picture %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, but you'll have to make sure @gon is defined everywhere and that any js library you need is defined too:

`# assets/javascripts/background_picture.js.erb`

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  if(gon.backgroundPicture) {
      var background = gon.backgroundPicture;
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + background +     ")";
   };     
 });

<% if current_user.try(:student?) || current_user.try(:supervisor?) %> 
  <% if current_user.background_picture != :null %>
    <% @gon.backgroundPicture = current_user.background_picture %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`# assets/javascripts/application.js`

`//= require background_picture`

Comment: Didn't work, says "undefined local variable or method current_user for Class"